# junit constructor runs AFTER test methods

Tags: java, junit, junit4

AFAIK before any method, constructor method is run by JRE.
But in my case, constructor is running after test methods.

```
import org.junit.*;
public class CourseTest {

    public CourseTest(){
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClassTest() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("beforeClassTest");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClassTest() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("afterClassTest");
    }

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("beforeTest");
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("afterTest");
    }


    @Test
    public void getCredit() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test 1 is getCredit");

    }

    @Test
    public void getName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test 2 is getName");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
beforeTest
test 2 is getName
afterTest
beforeTest
test 1 is getCredit
afterTest
beforeClassTest
Constructor
Constructor
afterClassTest
```

Not only that, my test cases are running in reverse order too.
Pretty confused by that.
I understand why constructor runs twice because for each test, a new class is instantiated. But how come constructor runs after test methods?

**Edit**:
As @mike-jenkins suggested, I debugged the test class and it runs in this order:

```
1-beforeClassTest
2-Constructor
3-beforeTest
4-test 2 is getName
5-afterTest
6-Constructor
7-beforeTest
8-test 1 is getCredit
9-afterTest
10-afterClassTest
```

Comment: It might not be possible to guarantee the order of tests, in any case each test case should be independent (FIRST principle), so the ordering should not matter.

Comment: The lifecyle methods of JUnit should be executed in a reproductive way. How do you execute your class ?

Comment: This could just be the output that is out of order, is it always the same result and what happens if you add a Thread.sleep to each method?

Comment: Add breakpoints to verify the output (as mentioned above)

Comment: @Ramazan: You can have a look at my answer

Comment: Don't know why someone down voted this question but this is a perfectly legit question. Also, the pluralsight course I am watching right now claims console output order to be as my edited section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of execution of the JUnit tests are NOT guaranteed as JUnit framework manages (internally) to run the tests in parallel. 
**This is to make the test execution faster which will be especially helpful when you are building the application in CI (Continuous Integration) environments where thousands of tests have to be run for the whole application.**

If you wanted to control the order of execution, you can use `@FixMethodOrder` annotation as below:

```
 @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
 public class MyTest {
    //your test code here
 }
```

> The default order of execution of JUnit tests within a class is
>   deterministic but not predictable. The order of execution is not
>   guaranteed for Java 7 (and some previous versions), and can even
>   change from run to run, so the order of execution was changed to be
>   deterministic (in JUnit 4.11)

You can look at [here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html)

**As there are multiple test cases, the constructor will be called multiple times (by different threads created by JUnit framework to execute them in parallel).**

As multiple threads are running, constructor's System.out.prinln() (infact any logs), can't be guaranteed that it will always be printed first (even though it has been invoked first). **In summary, in multi-threaded environments, you can't predict the order of logs and System.out.println() statements.**

Comment: OK, that's a good answer for test orders but how about the constructor being run after the test methods?

Comment: That is just for the tests, the question is also about why the constructor seems to be run twice, and the BeforeClass after the tests etc.

Comment: Constructor should run twice in this case, once for each test case. The ordering is as expected when I run it, which makes me think it could just be the output thats off

Comment: @DanielFigueroa Your question explained above